# What determines when mod_proxy only sometimes add internal ip addresses to X-Forwarded-For header

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, x-forwarded-for

I've been experimenting with Apache mod_proxy and mod_remoteip in order to confirm my understanding of the handling of X-Forwarded-For headers, particularly around how internal IP Addresses (e.g. 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x ranges) are being handled.

It seems like mod_proxy doesn't always add the internal IP addresses to the X-Forwarded-For header, but I've been unable to find any documentation explaining the expected behavior for this.

As far as I can tell, when the request initiates from an internal IP address, then mod_proxy will add internal IP addresses to the X-Forwarded-For header, but when the initial request comes from a public IP, mod_proxy does not seem to add any internal IP addresses to the X-Forwarded-For.

**The Question**

My question is: What are the rules that govern whether or not mod_proxy will append the calling IP address to the X-Forwarded-For header.

The [documentation on mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) says:

> When acting in a reverse-proxy mode (using the ProxyPass directive, for example), mod_proxy_http adds several request headers in order to pass information to the origin server. These headers are:
>
> *X-Forwarded-For* - 
>       The IP address of the client.
>
> *X-Forwarded-Host* - 
>       The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
>
> *X-Forwarded-Server* - 
>       The hostname of the proxy server.
>
> Be careful when using these headers on the origin server, since they will contain more than one (comma-separated) value if the original request already contained one of these headers. For example, you can use %{X-Forwarded-For}i in the log format string of the origin server to log the original clients IP address, but you may get more than one address if the request passes through several proxies.

I read this as saying that the client IP address will always be appended to the X-Forwarded-For header, but that's not the behavior I'm observing.

The rest of this question is the tests I've conducted and the behavior I've observed.

**The Setup**

I've setup two servers both running Apache with mod_proxy installed. I'll refer to these as One and Two.

- One has the (internal) IP address 10.0.7.1
- Two has the (internal) IP address 10.0.7.2

One has the following ProxyPass directive so that requests to sub-paths of /proxyToTwo are sent to the equivalent sub-path under /proxyToOne on Two

```
<Location "/proxyToTwo">
        ProxyPass http://10.0.7.2/proxyToOne
</Location>
```

Two has the following ProxyPass directive so that requests to sub-paths of /proxyToOne are sent back to One but without the /proxyToOne prefix

```
<Location "/proxyToOne">
        ProxyPass http://10.0.7.1
</Location>
```

The effect of this is that when I issue requests to `http://One/proxyToTwo/foo` it's proxied as follows

1. One receives the request, issues the following request to Two `http://10.0.7.2/proxyToOne/foo`
2. Two receives the request, issues the following request back to One `http://10.0.7.1/foo`
3. One receives a request for `/foo` and actually serves the resource

So every request is bounced from one to two and back to one before being responded two.

**Calling with an Internal IP**

Using the above setup, I call One from Two using it's internal IP address:

```
curl http://10.0.7.1/proxyToTwo/foo
```

The X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Host headers received when One eventually gets the request for the `/foo` resource is what I expect below:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.7.2, 10.0.7.1
X-Forwarded-Host: 10.0.7.1, 10.0.7.2
```

This is what I expect, that the request was proxied first through One then Two, and the requesting IP addresses are first the initial request from Two (curl) then the request from One (mod_proxy) and the final request (not in the header because it's the client IP of the connection being from Two (mod_proxy)

**Calling with external IP**

The unexpected behavior is that mod_proxy seems to behave differently when called from public IP. So Instead of calling One from Two, I call One from my local machine using the public address

```
curl http://35.162.28.102/proxyToTwo/foo
```

The X-Forwarded-Host is still what I expect:

```
X-Forwarded-Host: 35.162.28.102, 10.0.7.2
```

That is, the request was first proxied through One (using it's external address) then through Two.

But the X-Forwarded-For header is showing only my (external) IP address:

```
X-Forwarded-For: 35.163.25.76
```

This suggests to me that the initial execution of mod_proxy is adding the X-Forwarded-For header with the client IP address. But then the subsequent proxying by Two doesn't append the address of One.

I think this behavior is probably more useful than blindly appending the internal IP addresses to the header, but I can't find it documented anywhere so would like to ensure I fully understand it.

Comment: Having done an inspection of the mod_proxy code, I can't see anything that would cause the above behaviour. So my working theory is that this is actually caused by interaction between mod_proxy and mod_remoteip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this so it's available in-case others make a similar mistake.

In short: mod_proxy always appends the client IP to the X-Forwarded-For header (or adds an X-Forwarded-For header if there is no existing header).

But, other Apache modules can manipulate the X-Forwarded-For header prior to mod_proxy processing it. Mod_proxy will append the client IP to what it sees as the X-Forwarded-For header, which can be the output of other Apache modules.

In my tests, the other module affecting the result was [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html). The reason for the difference in resulting behavior was that I was using the [RemoteIpTrustedProxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html#remoteiptrustedproxy) directive to specify my trusted proxies and this will allow trusting of private IPs as the first connection but will not process private IPs in the X-Forwarded-For header.

As a result for the External IP case there was the following handling:

1. My Machine (`35.163.25.76`) connects to One with no X-Forwarded-For
2. One sends this request to Two with my IP in X-Forwarded-For header (`X-Forwarded-For: 35.163.25.76`)
3. Two receives this request, mod_remoteip processes the X-Forwarded-For header, because One is trusted, the client IP effectively is `35.163.25.76` and there is effectively no X-Forward-For header passed on to mod_proxy
4. Two sends this request to One with my IP in X-Forwarded-For header (`X-Forwarded-For: 35.163.25.76`)

This is what presents as "not appending the private IP" but is actually processing the X-Forward-For header and producing an identical one.

The Private ID case behaves differently because mod_remoteip isn't accepting the private IP address in the X-Forward for. So it's handled by:

1. Two (`10.0.7.2`) connects to One with no X-Forwarded-For
2. One sends this request to Two with Two's IP in X-Forwarded-For header (`X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.7.2`)
3. Two receives this request, mod_remoteip processes the X-Forwarded-For header but does not trust the value so leaves it as is. So the client IP remains One's IP (`10.0.7.1`) and the X-Forward-For header passed on to mod_proxy is unmodified
4. Two sends this request to One appending the client IP (One's) to X-Forwarded-For header resulting in `X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.7.2, 10.0.7.1`

I verified this by actually sending in some X-Forwarded-For headers from trusted hosts. E.g.

```
curl http://10.0.7.1/proxyToTwo/foo --header "X-Forwarded-For: TrustedHost1, TrustedHost2"
```

This results in the final X-Forward-For header containing only TrustedHost1 indicating that the header really is being processed by mod_remoteip and re-issued by mod_proxy.